# Firestore query document's field ID

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to do my query filtering for field id. I want to return all documents that contains a field id, and then it's value.

[image]

In this example I want to do something like:

```
db.collection("assistencia").where(">>> 0qSzBxVimwRlurLHNzXp EXIST <<<<") <=== I don't know what I need to put here
.get()
.then(function(querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
        // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
        console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
    });
})
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: It kind of seems like you have your keys and your values backward. Have you just recently started this project or is it too late to change that?

Comment: I can change it, but I think this is the best method because I have a lot of docs that contains fields from other collection doc.id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll be very very blunt: you are using not only Firestore wrong, but ANY data base wrong.

As mentioned, Firestore does not offer any queries that check for the existence of a field.  BUT that doesn't mean you can't query for documents that DO have a field.

Firestore also doesn't have "wildcards", but that doesn't mean you can't query for all values...

So: when you query on a field, Firestore will ***ONLY*** return documents that *have* the field.

Also: you can use a "greater than" query with the value of NULL - ***any*** value at all is great than NULL.

So to get all the documents that ***have*** the field "Retard"

```
db.collection("assistencia").where("Retard", ">", /000)
```

This will return literally ***all*** documents in that collection that *have* a "Retard" field with a non-null value.  Use of this technique is ***VERY VERY HIGHLY NOT RECOMMENDED***.  It will not scale.  I *have* done such a thing for a one-time extremely hacky transfer from one data structure to another - never for client-facing.

To get all the documents with a specific value for "Retard"

```
db.collection("assistencia").where("Retard", "==", "0qSzBxVimwRlurLHNzXp")
```

You only get to use a database the way it is designed to be used.

Comment: Ok, then if I have a collection "children" with all children information, how can I store all children's assitant of every day? I have more than 250 days to store.... I need to do then queries like all assistants, no assistands, retards, etc... and all assist from one children too.

Comment: I'll be blunt, again - I really have no idea what exactly you are trying to do here.

Comment: I needed it again but finally i decide to module my db with more consistent structure. Thanks anyway for all!

Answer (score 0):

Firestore does not offer any queries that check for the existence of a field.  Your data model should take this fact into account.

If you want to check if a string is available among other strings, you can add a list field and use an array-contains query to find documents where that string is present in the list.  If the field is named "items":

```
db.collection("assistencia").where("items", "array-contains", "0qSzBxVimwRlurLHNzXp")
```

You would then have the document with the data you want, and you could check the other fields for the value in the document you're looking for.

Comment: I can't do that because then I need to query for the belue inside this ids. So, I need to return all documents with "Retard" data... And then I want their field.id for consult another table that returns all information by this id

Comment: Well, you need to make some change to your schema because, as a I said at the beginning, Firestore does not offer any queries that check for existence of a field.  You should always design your document to suit the capabilities of Firestore.